# PHP URL redirection

Tags: php, forms, url

I am working on a site locally and I am trying to add a contact form to it.

I've added a simple form on: `http:localhost:8888/testsite/contact.php`, when the user clicks on the submit button I want them to be redirected to another page with a message on it. The page I want the user to go to after submitting the form it: `contact_message.php`.

I've created both files and they both display OK on there URLs- `http:localhost:8888/testsite/contact.php` and `http:localhost:8888/testsite/contact-message.php` however the form isn't working because when you click submit the url changes to: `http:localhost:8888/testsite/contact.php/contact-message.php`, which would be fine if it showed the `contact-message.php` content, but it doesn't.

The code fore the form is:

```
<form method="post" action="contact-message.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="message">Message</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <textarea type="text" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: are you sure the contact-message.php script is actually working? a syntax error could kill the script before ANY output is performed, leaving you with a blank browser. e.g. do some basic debugging yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a full path or relative path to the correct file in your form action. Currently, you are telling the form to submit to the current url plus contact-message.php. Instead try...

```
<form method="post" action="http:localhost:8888/testsite/contact-message.php">
```

Or simply..

```
<form method="post" action="/contact-message.php">
```

which tells it to use the base URL + /contact-message.php

Comment: If i use:                                                           `<form method="post" action="/contact-message.php">` Then that makes the url `http://localhost:8888/contact-message.php` instead of `http://localhost:8888/testsite/contact-message.php`

Comment: I had no way of knowing if your base url was localhost:8888 or localhost:8888/testsite as either could be configured. In this case, you can just change it to action="/testsite/contact-message.php"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code if your send mail function return true:

```php
header("Location: http://localhost:8888/testsite/contact_message.php");
```

PHP header documentation: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the form tag with:

```
<form method="post" action="./contact-message.php">
```

This will then call the contact-message.php file that is located in the same folder. The dot is the beginning f a relative path starting at the current position